# How to discard the rest of line after syntax error

Tags: yacc, lex, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm implementing a small shell, and using lex&yacc to parse command.  Lex reads command from `stdin` and yacc execute the command after `yyparse`.

The problem is, when there is a syntax error, yacc prompt an error and parse from the begining.  In this case, `cmd1 >>> cmd2` leads to running `cmd2` becuase `>>>` is a syntax error.

My question is how to discard the rest of current command after encounting a syntax error?

Comment: Try adding this rule, at the higher level: `| error '\n' { yyerrok; } `  -- see [the bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/html_node/Simple-Error-Recovery.html) for more info..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write an interactive language with a prompt that lets users enter expressions, it's a bad idea to simply use yacc on the entire input stream.  Yacc might get confused about something on one line and then misinterpret subsequent lines. For instance, the user might have an unbalanced parenthesis on the first line. or a string literal which is not closed, and then yacc will just keep consuming subsequent lines of the input, looking to close the construct.

It's better to gather the line of input from the user, and then parse that as one unit. The end of the line then simply the end of the input as far as Yacc is concerned.

If you're using lex, there are ways to redirect lex to read characters from a buffer in memory instead of from a `FILE *` stream. Look for documentation on the `YY_INPUT` macro, which you can define in a Lex file to basically specify the code that Lex uses for obtaining input characters.

---

**Analogy time:** Using a scanner developed with lex/yacc for directly handling interactive user input is a little bit like [using `scanf` for handling user input](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).  Whereas capturing a line into a buffer and then parsing it is more like using `sscanf`. Quote:

> It's perfectly appropriate to parse strings with sscanf (as long as the return value is checked), because it's so easy to regain control, restart the scan, **discard the input** if it didn't match, etc. [comp.lang.c FAQ, 12.20].